# How to use data structures in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, programming, arrays, expl3

I created a foreach statement, using [`expl3`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3) and [`TikZ/pgf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \Counter #1 \Stopper { \tl_length:n {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{countarray}{1}{\edef\pgfmathresult{\Counter#1\Stopper}}
\begin{document}
%array with names
\def\names{{"Katie","Frank","Laura"}}

%find the last element index
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Last}{countarray(\names) - 1}

%print all the elements of array
\foreach \i in {0,...,\Last} {%
  \i: \pgfmathparse{\names[\i]}\pgfmathresult\\
}
\end{document}
```

Prints this:

[image]

Suppose I want to use different colors for different names (or setting any other parameters). Getting something like this:

```
Katie\\
\textcolor{blue}{Frank}\\
Laura
```

[image]

In Perl, I would have done something like this:

```
my @data = (
  {"text" => "Katie"},
  {"text" => "Frank", "color" => "blue"},
  {"text" => "Laura"});

foreach(@data)
{
      if(defined($_->{color}))
      {
            print "\textcolor\{$_->{color}\}\{$_->{text}\}";
      }
      else
      {
            print $_->{text};
      }
      print "\\\\";
}
```

Is it possible to implement this in `expl3`?

Comment: Is there a reason for storing the names in the format you have rather than a normal comma list? Can we use just `expl3` data constructs to make everything work? Are we allowed a separate 'color' data structure to hold the info or does it all need to be in one place?

Comment: @JosephWright The benefit of storing data in this format is that it allows to have some values missing in the record. While in a comma separated list (array), you'll have to have empty cells.

Comment: Does it need to be `expl3`? I would have suggested something between [Ryan Reich’s](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107978/16595) and [Claudio Fiandrino’s](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108097/16595) answer. — How do you want the input to look like without an empty-cells containing comma-separated list?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel "Does it need to be expl3?" No, tikz is ok. I need to test the answers myself to fully understand, how to use them. Just need some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, we want our code to support 2 properties of text: color and italics. At first we define the plists:

```
%plist1 definition
\prop_new:N \l_list_a_prop
\prop_put:Nnn \l_list_a_prop { text } {Katie}

%plist2 definition
\prop_new:N \l_list_b_prop
\prop_put:Nnn \l_list_b_prop { text } {Frank}
\prop_put:Nnn \l_list_b_prop { color } {red}

%plist3 definition
\prop_new:N \l_list_c_prop
\prop_put:Nnn \l_list_c_prop { text } {Laura}
\prop_put:Nnn \l_list_c_prop { color } {blue}
\prop_put:Nnn \l_list_c_prop { italic } {yes}
```

Mind, that expl3 doesn't support numbers in the names, that's why I used `_a`, `_b`, `_c`.

Then put all the plists into a sequence:

```
%putting plists to sequence
\seq_new:N \l_my_seq
\seq_push:Nn \l_my_seq { \l_list_c_prop }
\seq_push:Nn \l_my_seq { \l_list_b_prop }
\seq_push:Nn \l_my_seq { \l_list_a_prop }
```

Then we loop through the sequence and put the appropriate markup to the text if necessary:

```
\tl_new:N \__text
\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_my_seq
{
  \prop_get:NnN #1 { text } \__text

  \prop_get:NnNT #1 { color } \color_tl
  {
    \protected@edef \__text {\textcolor{\color_tl}{\__text}}
  }

  \prop_get:NnNT #1 { italic } \italic_tl
  {
    \protected@edef \__text {\textit{\__text}}
  }

  \__text\\
}
```

Altogether we have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{color}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

%plist1 definition
\prop_new:N \l_list_a_prop
\prop_put:Nnn \l_list_a_prop { text } {Katie}

%plist2 definition
\prop_new:N \l_list_b_prop
\prop_put:Nnn \l_list_b_prop { text } {Frank}
\prop_put:Nnn \l_list_b_prop { color } {red}

%plist3 definition
\prop_new:N \l_list_c_prop
\prop_put:Nnn \l_list_c_prop { text } {Laura}
\prop_put:Nnn \l_list_c_prop { color } {blue}
\prop_put:Nnn \l_list_c_prop { italic } {yes}

%putting plists to sequence
\seq_new:N \l_my_seq
\seq_push:Nn \l_my_seq { \l_list_c_prop }
\seq_push:Nn \l_my_seq { \l_list_b_prop }
\seq_push:Nn \l_my_seq { \l_list_a_prop }

\tl_new:N \__text
\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_my_seq
{
  \prop_get:NnN #1 { text } \__text

  \prop_get:NnNT #1 { color } \color_tl
  {
    \protected@edef \__text {\textcolor{\color_tl}{\__text}}
  }

  \prop_get:NnNT #1 { italic } \italic_tl
  {
    \protected@edef \__text {\textit{\__text}}
  }

  \__text\\
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

This will print:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I don't know about `expl3` but it is possible within TikZ, or rather, within `pgfkeys`.  Since there is an `l3keys` submodule of LaTeX3, I assume basically the same idea works there.  You can create your data structure in much the same way as in Perl:

```
\pgfkeys{
 /names/.cd,
 make name/.style = {
  #1/color/.initial = black
 },
 make name/.list = {Katie, Frank, Laura},
 Frank/color = blue
}
```

Then you can extract the color of a name via, say:

```
\newcommand\getcolor[1]{%
 \pgfkeysgetvalue{/names/#1/color}%
}
```

which is fully expandable and can be used wherever you need the color of a name.  Of course, for this example there is no need for the single subkey `Frank/color` (you could just set `Frank/.initial = blue`) but if you want more properties, you can add them by giving them their own named subkeys as well.

Comment: The `pgfkeys` approach is object-oriented, which the keyval support in LaTeX3 is not. So you'd need a different approach: I'll try to suggest one later.

Answer (score 3):

*This ultimately does not answer to the question:*

> Is it possible to implement this in `expl3`?

*thus it is marked community wiki.*

Besides the interesting aspect of dealing with `expl3`, this job is perfectly doable just with the standard syntax of TikZ foreach in combination with [`xstring`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} % won't work just with pgffor
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}

\foreach \name [count=\i from 0]in{Katie,Frank=>blue,Laura=>red}{
   \IfSubStr{\name}{=>}{% true
     \StrCut{\name}{=>}\xname\namecol
     \i: \textcolor{\namecol}{\xname}\par%
   }{% false
     \i: \name\par%
   }
}

\end{document}
```

This provides:

[image]

The idea behind is more or less like this:

1. look for the separator string (`=>` in the example);
2. if present cut the string into two parts (name and color) and use them;
3. if not present, use the standard syntax.

Of course, it is possible to:

- change separator string;
- do much more complicated things (i.e. adding more properties: just nest some conditionals or, in a simpler manner, define one separator string per property).

Comment: I think you're being overly modest in making this CW.  It's not uncommon to give alternate solutions and the original question was not heavily LaTeX3-oriented; I suspect the poster was trying to learn about LaTeX programming rather than was tied to this particular model of it.  And there are so many models.

Comment: I agree with you, but I've marked it as CW following the policy proposed by Charles in his meta answer to [Best practise for answers which are for the community, not the OP (“tikz answer to pstricks question”)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3453/13304) since this might be the case.